# Can SSRS Reports be used without a SQL Server Database?

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, objectdatasource

I have an application that gets all its data from an old AS400 application.

I get a model out (what in MVC I'd call a ViewModel) that has all the data for the reports, but the current legacy code is using the windows forms drawing API to place each box and label and data value on the report. It is hard-coded and maintenance is what you'd expect in terms of nightmare level.

I want to switch over to a report based on the data object or a collection thereof. I know how to write code against an object data source in ASP.Net, but I was wondering if the same can be done using SSRS for the report design, then using the objects collection as the data source. Has anyone done this?

Joey Morgan

Comment: SSRS = SQL Server Reporting Services, you need a Report Server to deploy the reports you create otherwise you cannot share them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS is very extensible and you can write your own [custom data processing extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152816%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) that processes whatever data you have (in your case, the objects collection) and turns it into a dataset.

I've done this and while it isn't trivial, it isn't as hard as you might think and implementing a custom data processing extension may be a good way to solve your problem. There are plenty of examples online to get you started. I based mine on the [file share example](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160918(v=sql.90).aspx) provided with SSRS that queries a network folder and returns the file information as a dataset.

Comment: It turns out this won't work because the customers won't have an SSRS server. I will need a different solution. However this DOES answer my question, so I am marking it as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant where the data source was not a SQL database, not where they didn't have SQL entirely. You could always use [SQL Server Express with Advanced Services](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx) - its free and includes SSRS.